# goto functions after press enter React problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I do not understand why pressing enter does not make me enter this function. How should I write it?

other onClick events work fine, but when I try to do it this way, it does not work.

how can I resolve this problem?

```
 handleFormSubmit = (variant) => (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { activeStep, email } = this.state;
    if (activeStep === 4 && email === '') {
      document.getElementsByTagName('input').email.value = '';
      this.setState({
        error: <FormattedMessage {...messages.inputEmailAddressEmpty} />,
      });
      return;
    }

    this.Auth.isEmail(this.state.email).then((res) => {
      if (!res.isEmail) {
        this.Auth.register(
          this.state.login,
          this.state.password,
          this.state.name,
          this.state.surname,
          this.state.email,
        )
          .then((register) => {
            if (!register.error) {
              this.setState({
                activeStep: activeStep + 1,
              });

              this.props.enqueueSnackbar(<FormattedMessage {...messages.succesCreated} />, {
                variant,
              });
              this.props.history.replace('/login');
            } else {
              this.setState({
                error: <FormattedMessage {...messages.invalidEmail} />,
              });

            }
          })
          .catch(() => {
            this.setState({
              error: <FormattedMessage {...messages.errorServer} />,
            });
          });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          error: <FormattedMessage {...messages.existAccountWithSameEmail} />,
        });
      }
    });
  };

...


     <Fragment>
        <div className={classes.textField}><FormattedMessage {...messages.emailAddress} /></div>

        <FormattedMessage {...messages.inputEmail}>
          {(placeholder) => (
            <input
              key={5}
              className={classNames(classes.formItem, {
                [classes.formError]: error,
              })}
              placeholder={placeholder}
              name="email"
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              onKeyPress={(ev) => {
                if (ev.key === 'Enter') {
                  ev.preventDefault();
                  this.handleFormSubmit('success');
                }
              }}
            />
          )}
        </FormattedMessage>

        {error ? <div className={classes.textError}>{error}</div> : null}
      </Fragment>
```

I do not understand why pressing enter does not make me enter this function. How should I write it?

other onClick events work fine, but when I try to do it this way, it does not work.

how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: try replacing `ev.key === 'Enter'` with `ev.key == 'Enter'`  or   `ev.charCode == 13`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`handleFormSubmit('success')` return funtion. Try this

```
 onKeyPress={(ev) => {
     if (ev.key === 'Enter') {
          this.handleFormSubmit('success')(ev);
     }
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ev.which` or `ev.keycode == 13`